# How to properly index attributes in wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, database-design

I am extending a product sales plugin and am trying to understand how wordpress handles database relations. I am building tables on activation using `dbDelta`. An example of a table schema would be:

```
$table_schema = [
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$wpdb->prefix}plugin_orders` (
          `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `people_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          `order_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          `order_status` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `order_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
          `order_total` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
          `accounting` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          KEY `people_id` (`people_id`),
          KEY `order_id` (`order_id`)
        ) $collate;",

        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$wpdb->prefix}plugin_order_product` (
          `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `order_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          `product_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          KEY `order_id` (`order_id`),
          KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
        ) $collate;"
    ];
```

I see that `id` in each table is the `PRIMARY KEY` but what does declaring the other `KEY`s actually do? I have read that wordpress uses MyISAM which doesn't actually build foreign key connections. While these tables may point to other tables already existing, in this example does declaring `KEY order_id (order_id)` create a variable of sorts called `order_id` that any other table can use to reference? Is this code specifically connecting one tables attributes to another tables attributes (it doesn't appear to be)? After these tables are built, I can inspect them in phpMyAdmin and see that there are indexes assigned but no foreign key constraints. How does this code create tables that point one table at another to build relations?

Answer (score 0):

```
KEY `foo_bar` (`order_id`)
```

"KEY" is the same as "INDEX".  It specifies that a separate data structure is maintained for the efficient access of the table via the column `order_id`.

`foo_bar` is the name of the index.  It has no special meaning, and has very few uses.  For example, `DROP KEY foo_bar;` is the way to get rid of the index.

In MyISAM, a "FOREIGN KEY" allowed, but ignored. In InnoDB, it does two things:

- Create an index if one is not already provided
- Provide a constraint.  The default effectively "complain if the other table does not already have the value referenced".

Having an index is important for performance.  The index above make this

```
SELECT ... WHERE order_id = 1234 ...
```

run in milliseconds, even if there are billions of rows in the table.  Without the index, the query would take minutes or hours.

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key, which is an `INDEX`.

`UNIQUE(widget)` says that only one row can have a particular value of `widget in the table.

`PRIMARY KEY(id)` says that each row is uniquely identified by the column `id`.  InnoDB really wants each table to have a PK.

"`id`" is a convention (not a requirement) for the name of the PK.  It is also `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` by convention.  You may or may not actually ever touch `id`.

Tables can be related to each other in 3 main ways:

1:1 -- They share the same unique key.  This is rarely useful; you may as well have a single table.

1:many -- An "order" has several "items" in it (one-order : many-items).  This is usually handled by `order_id` being a column in the `items` table.

many:many -- `students_classes` -- each student is in many classes; each class has many students.  This is implemented via a mapping table that has (usually) only two columns:  `student_id` and `class_id` (no `id` is needed) and `PRIMARY KEY(student_id, class_id)` and `INDEX(class_id, student_id)`.  Those two indexes make it efficient to go from a known student to their classes, and vice versa.

Another convention for the PK of a table is to include the table name.  (It is clutter to do that for other columns, such as `order_status`.)  I was assuming this convention for `student_id` and `class_id`.

But now I am confused by your `plugin_orders` -- it has both `id` and `order_id`.  If that table describes "orders", then I would expect `order_id` to be the PK instead of `id`.

And, if `order_product` is a list of all the "products" in each "order", then I would expect you to have the 1:many pattern.

What indexes to have?

- `PRIMARY KEY` to uniquely identify each row -- either `id` or some column (or combination of columns) that are unique.
- Other columns, as needed, for the `SELECTs`, `UPDATEs`, and `DELETEs` that you have.  *Do not blindly add indexes before having some clues of the queries that might need them.*

Indexes sometimes help in sorting:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

together with

```
INDEX(last_name, first_name)
```

Indexes provide performance;  FKs provide integrity checks.  Neither is "required"; both are "desirable".

MyISAM is ancient; you should change to InnoDB.

Then do something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM plugin_orders AS o
    JOIN plugin_order_product AS op
           ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    WHERE ...
```

In this example, the Optimizer will perform the query something like this:

1. Look at the `WHERE` to see which table is best filtered by the conditions there.  Declare that to be the first table work with.
2. Scan through the first table, using an index if practical.
3. For each row in the first table, reach into the second table.
4. Reaching into the second table would probably be done via `INDEX(order_id)` on the second table.  This would make the `JOIN` fast and efficient.

Both tables have `INDEX(order_id)`, but that is not relevant.

Next example:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM plugin_orders AS o
    JOIN plugin_order_product AS op
           ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    WHERE o.people_id = 123   -- note
```

1. Pick `o` as the first table due to filtering on `people_id`
2. use `op` `INDEX(people_id)` to rapidly find the `o` rows that are relevant.
3. etc (`op` is the second table)

Next example:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM plugin_orders AS o
    JOIN plugin_order_product AS op
           ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    WHERE op.product_id = 9887    -- changed again
```

1. Pick `op` as the first table due to filtering on `product_id`
2. use `o` `INDEX(people_id)` to rapidly find the `op` rows that are relevant.
3. etc (`o` is the second table this time)

Comment: I generally understand indexes/FKs but in this example if I claim one column is a `KEY` or index, how do I link it to another table without defining its relationship? if table 1 has `order_id` as a key and I have metadata in another table listing all items in the order and have a column of `order_id` does it know they are linked? Do I need to define all the order_id columns as `KEY` in each table? I'm looking to understand this structure as that's how all of wordpress works but every example on the internet I can find defines strict foreign keys and connections.

Comment: The original example is from a plugin that is extending woocommerce so it may not be showing all of the columns it needs to connect to. I was just trying to show the syntax for how wordpress `$wpdb` uses to create new tables and assign primary keys and indexes so that example may not be complete for where the table connections refer too.

Comment: actually this is using `dbDelta` and not `$wpdb` to create the tables. I'll change the post to reflect

Comment: @JasonH - I added a crude example of `JOIN`.  It may or may not be valid, depending on the semantics of the tables.  That `SELECT` does not depend on any `INDEX` or FK, though it would like such.

Comment: ok, so an index (KEY) creates another table of sorts to find those records faster? Using the example tables from above, if I add a `KEY` to `order_id` from `plugin_order` table but then search through `plugin_order_product` for all products by `order_id` will the `KEY` defined in the first table speed up a query of the second table? or will I also need to define `order_id` as a key in `plugin_order_product` table?

Comment: @JasonH - more examples

Comment: @RickJames and I have just rolled out a (free, GPL) WordPress plugin to add high(er)-performance indexes to some busy WordPress tables.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/